# Any ideas on how i could create a "Object collision detection" with the code i have here?

Tags: java, processing

Im trying to make a game were if the main character (`gubbe`) collides with the enemy (`fiende`) the character will take `damage(Healthdisplay/HW)`. ive tried to make a collision detection thing in many ways, mainly `if(x.intersects(y)){}`. Im stuck and don't know how to solve it. ill put the main code down here VVV. if more code is needed just say and ill put in the needed code.

HW is the hp-pool were the damage should be done to.

void display is were the main character/rectangle is created.

the enemy is in another page in processing.

```java
class gubbe {

    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    int HW = 20;
    //rect sidor
    int h1 = 100;
    int w1 = 100;
    //----

    //VV movement VV
    void move() {

    if (keyPressed) {
        if (key == 'w' || key == 'W') {
            //terms, move forward, Y-led.
            y -= 100;
        }
    }
    if (keyPressed) {
        if (key == 'a' || key == 'A') {
            //terms, move right, X-led.
            x -= 100;
        }
    }
    if (keyPressed) {
        if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {
            //terms, move backwards, Y-led.
            y += 100;
        }
    }
    if (keyPressed) {
        if (key == 'd' || key == 'D') {
            //terms, move left, X-led.
            x += 100;
        }
    }
}

// VV visual VV
void display() {
    //Grabb
    fill(127);
    stroke(0);
    rect(x, y, w1, h1);
}

void display2() {
    fill(127);
    stroke(0);
    rect(x, y, w1, h1);
}

// VV Edgechechning VV
void checkEdges() {
    if (x + 100 > width) {
        x -= 50;
    } else if (x < 0) {
        x += 50;
    } else if (y > height) {
        y -= 50;
    } else if (y < 0) {
        y += 50;
    } else {
    }
}

// VV Fighting VV
void Fight() {
    if (keyPressed) {

        if (key == 'm'|| key == 'M') {
            //villkor, flytta höger, X-led.
            fill(255, 0, 0);
            stroke(255, 0, 0);
            rect(x, y-100, 100, 100);
        }
    }
}

// VV  health bars VV
void BarsDisplay() {
    fill(204, 204, 204);
    stroke(204, 204, 204);
    rect(x, y-30, 100, 9);
}

void HealthDisplay() {
    fill(0, 0, 255);
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    rect(x, y-31, HW, 3);
    !!! here there should be collision detection!!!

}

void XpDisplay() {
    fill(255, 255, 0);
    stroke(255, 255, 0);
    rect(x, y-22, 2, 1);
    //if(om dödar fiende){
    //  width+=x
    //}
    //else{
    //}
}
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for the algorithm to know if two shapes are overlapping, or about a way to make this kind of algorithm work in your context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Objects seem to be in rectangular shape, so a collision takes place if the distance between both centers along the x-axis as well as the y-axis is smaller than half the size of each object in direction of that axis added up.

Take a piece of paper and sketch it down, then you will see it!

Comment: *"Take a piece of paper and sketch it down, then you will see it!*" is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A method in the class `gubbe` which checks for an intersection against an object of type `fiende` may look as follows (I've assuming that `fiende` is a rectangle and has the attributes `x`, `y`, `w1`, `h1`:

```java
class gubbe {

    // [...]

    Boolean intersects(fiende f){

        // if intersecting then return 'true', else return 'false'    
        return this.x < f.x+f.w1 && f.x < this.x+this.w1 && 
               this.y < f.y+f.h1 && f.y < this.y+this.h1;
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Call the method like this:

```java
gubbe g = new gubbe();
gubbe f = new fiende();

if (g.intersects(f)) {
   // do somthing
   // [...]
}
```

---

Explanation:

To check for a collision of to rectangles, you've to check if the rectangles are overlapping in both dimensions.

For a range from `x1` to `x1+w1` and a second range from `x2` to `x2+w2`, there are the following possible cases:

Not overlapping:

```
x1      x1+w1
  +----+
            +----+
          x2      x2+w2
```

```
           x1      x1+w1
             +----+
  +----+
x2      x2+w2
```

Overlapping

```
x1                x1+w1
  +--------------+
       +----+
     x2      x2+w2
```

```
     x1      x1+w1
       +----+
  +---------------+
x2                 x2+w2
```

```
x1           x1+w1
  +---------+
       +----------+
     x2            x2+w2
```

```
     x1            x1+w1
       +----------+
  +----------+
x2            x2+w2
```

This mean, that the ranges are overlapping if

```
x1 < x2+w2 AND x2 < x1+w1
```

For 2 rectangles which are defined by origin and a size (`x1`, `y1`, `w1` `h1`) respectively (`x2`, `y2`, `w2` `h2`) the condition is:

```
x1 < x2+w2 AND x2 < x1+w1 AND y1 < y2+h2 AND y2 < y1+h1
```

This leads to the following function:

```java
Boolean intersect(float x1, float y1, float w1, float h1,
                  float x2, float y2, float w2, float h2){

    // if intersecting then return 'true', else return 'false'
    return x1 < x2+w2 && x2 < x1+w1 && 
           y1 < y2+h2 && y2 < y1+h1;
}
```